# Multiple Lebesgue integrals: counting measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am completing an exercise on multiple Lebesgue integrals. The problem is as follows:

Let $X=Y=\Bbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{P}\Bbb{N}$ with counting measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ respectively. Define
$$f\colon X\times Y\to\Bbb{R}\quad\text{by}\quad f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1, &\text{if}\;x=y\\
-1, &\text{if}\;x=y+1\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Show that $\int_Y\left(\int_X f\,d\mu\right)\,d\nu$ and $\int_X\left(\int_Y f\,d\nu\right)\,d\mu$ exist and are unequal.

I tried to solve this but I found them both to be zero, so I am doing something wrong. My argument is below.

---

First consider
$$\int_X f\,d\mu=\sum_{x\in X}\int_{\{x\}}f\,d\mu=\sum_{x\in X} f(x,y)\mu(\{x\})=\sum_{x\in X} f(x,y),$$
by linearity of the integral, and then since $f$ is simple on each $\{x\}$. But summing over the natural numbers (i.e. $X$) yields $$\sum_{x\in X} f(x,y)=1+(-1)+0+0+\dots=0$$
for each fixed $y$. Then the double integral is
$$\int_Y\left(\int_X f\,d\mu\right)\,d\nu=\int_Y 0\,d\nu=0.$$

But now I think this argument would be identical if done in the $Y$ case, i.e.
$$\int_Y f\,d\nu=\sum_{y\in Y} f(x,y)=1+(-1)+0+0+\dots=0.$$

---

Any hints at where I have made a mistake are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\sum_{x \geq 0}\sum_{y \geq 0} f(x,y) = \sum_{x \geq 0}\left(f(x,0) + f(x,1) + \cdots \right) = 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 0.
$$
However,
$$
\sum_{y \geq 0}\sum_{x \geq 0} f(x,y) = \sum_{y \geq 0}\left( f(0,y) + f(1,y) + \cdots\right) = 1 + [(-1) + 1] + 0 + \dots = 1.
$$
This is because $f(0,y)$ never attains the value $-1$.

Comment: Obvious mistake.... thanks for pointing it out! (P.S. I think your series are the wrong way around when calculated, the first is equal to $1$, the second $0$? $\sum_y f(0,y)=1$ is the first term in your first series.)

Comment: You'r welcome. I think the sums are correct this way?

Comment: $$\sum_x\sum_y f(x,y)=\sum_y f(0,y) + \sum_y f(1,y) + \dots = 1+0+0+\dots, $$
and 
$$\sum_y\sum_x f(x,y)=\sum_x f(x,0)+\sum_x f(x,1)+\dots=0+0+\dots.$$

Comment: yes of course my mistake